# replicating trees between ACID RDB using CRDT

Tags: crdt

I'm interested in replicating "hierachies" of data say similar to addresses.

Area
District
Sector
Unit

but you may have different pieces of data associated to each layer, so you may know the area of Sectors, but not of units, and you may know the population of a unit, basically its not a homogenious tree.

I know little about replication of data except brushing Brewers theorem/CAP, and some naive intuition about what eventual consistency is.

I'm looking for SIMPLE mechanisms to replicate this data from an ACID RDB, into other ACID RDBs, systemically the system needs to eventually converge, and obviously each RDB will enforce its own local consistent view, but any 2 nodes may not match at any given time (except 'eventually').

The simplest way to approach this is to simple store all the data in a single message from some designated leader and distribute it...like an overnight dump and load process, but thats too big.

So the next simplest thing (I thought) was if something inside an area changes, I can export the complete set of data inside an area, and load it into the nodes, thats still quite a coarse algorithm.

The next step was if, say an 'object' at any level changed, was to send all the data in the path to that 'object', i.e. if something in a sector is amended, you would send the data associated to the sector, its parent the district, and its parent the sector (with some sort of version stamp and lets say last update wins)....what i wanted to do was to ensure that any replication 'update' was guaranteed to succeed (so it needs the whole path, which potentially would be created if it didn't exist).

then i stumbled on CRDTs and thought....ah...I'm reinventing the wheel here, and the algorithms are allegedly easy in principle, but tricky to get correct in practice

are there standards accepted patterns to do this sort of thing?

In my use case the hierarchies are quite shallow, and there is only a single designated leader (at this time), I'm quite attracted to state based CRDTs because then I can ignore ordering.

Simplicity is the key requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it appears I've reinvented (in a very crude naive way) the SHELF algorithm.

I'll write some code and see if I can get it to work, and try to understand whats going on.